# Electron prompt support

Tags: macos, npm, native, prompt, electron

I am looking for a native (OS X) prompt module when working on Electron, something like the window popped up when I click 'Join Other Network...':
[image]

This offers the ability to get inputs and process the data returned. So `Dialog` in Electron may not work here (at least I did not figure it out). I found [this issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/472), but I cannot understand it.

Right now my approach is to open up a browserWindow to to ipc with main thread, but the most critical issue is that, it does not feel like native!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Electron currently does not have this functionality built in. As far as I know this UI is fully custom, the OS API does not have a direct way to create this UI. For this reason it is likely Electron will never have this functionality.

Your only options are to mimic the native UI in CSS or create a node module that accesses the OS APIs to build your desired UI.